# How to vertical align button contents with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, google-material-icons

I am using bootstrap 4 and material icons in my app. The problem is when I have a button with both text and an icon.

```css
.button-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-icon">
    <i class="material-icons">account_box</i>
    My Account
</button>
```

I've tried changing the font size for the icon but that throws off the size of other icons throughout the page.

I am just trying to get the text to line center with the icon. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Those are vertically aligned by default. You need to post the full HTML output if you want help with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to do it is with the [Flexbox utility](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) classes, `.d-flex .align-items-center` in this case.

```html
<button class="btn button-icon d-flex align-items-center">
    <i class="material-icons">account_box</i>
    My Account
</button>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Beautiful! Just what I was looking for.